# WordPress add slash in URL on 1 page

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url

I have some problem with WordPress.

On the news page WordPress add `/` in the end of URL (example: `mysite.com/news.html/`).
On another pages all it's okay, (example, `mysite.com/page.html`).

Can anyone say me how delete `/` on the news page?

Maybe problem with *.htaccess*:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Maybe problem in this line: `prntscr.com/1yqevq` but if I change for `ptk-avtom.ru/%postname%`. Without `/`, all pages are in 404 error.

Comment: Is `mysite.com/news.html` a static html file or a WordPress page?

Comment: if all other pages are fine, parmalinks are working. Check navigation link (in menu) for news page. If its post or page type, check slug and link in edit mode.

Comment: mysite.com/news.html wordpress page .
Real page http://www.ptk-avtom.ru/novosti.html/
Other pages - http://www.ptk-avtom.ru/cash.html , without '/'

Answer (score 1):

Try to add this one in your .htaccess file:

```
# remove trailing slash
RewriteRule ^(.*)\/(\?.*)?$ $1$2 [R=301,L]
```

Thanks

Comment: Maybe problem in this line:http://prntscr.com/1yqevq
But if i change for :http://www.ptk-avtom.ru/%postname%  .Without "/" , all pages are 404 error